# VMware PowerCLI - Mass Revert Snapshot

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm trying to revert an array of VM's (created from C:\esx\vmlist.txt) to snapshot "test" (all were snapshot at the same time with a snapshot named "test").

Here's my script:

```
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core

Connect-VIServer -Server 192.168.10.10 -User root -Password mypass

$VMs = Get-Content'C:\esx\vmlist.txt'

$snapname = Read-Host 'Snapshot Name:'

Get-Snapshot -VM $VMs -Name $snapname -confirm:$false
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To revert snapshot, you would use `Set-VM` cmdlet:

```
Get-Snapshot -VM $VMs -Name $snapname | Foreach-Object {
    Set-VM -VM $_.VM -Snapshot $_ -Confirm:$false
}
```

Just in case: you may want to run this with `-WhatIf` (instead of `-Confirm:$false`) first.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I had to remove the first -Confirm:$false as that would not run.

Comment: This part was actually copy/ paste from your code, now removed/ updated as suggested. Glad I could help. :)